# 3rd Party Key Storage Providers

Tags: security, cryptography, storage

Can we persist keys in 3rd party key stores? We do not want to store in Microsoft Keys Store. Any clue for such providers and samples/documentation will be helpful.

Comment: It wouldn't be very useful to have hardware CSP's if you could not use the keys in them, right? Normally you'd generate or derive keys in them in the first place of course, no need for insecure key storage in memory.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes there's more than one way to skin a cat ... emm, to use the cryptographic key. Cloud Key Storages include their own APIs, and that's what OP was asking about, if I got him right.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, [Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) in Microsoft Azure is what you are looking for.

The problem, however, is that at the moment this API is not easily useable in a transparent manner, i.e. you need to explicitly call API functions via the provided Vault SDK.